# Using Google App Engine modules for multi-thread backend update of a Cloud endpoints project

Tags: maven, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

I'm building "read-only" webservice (Google Cloud Endpoints as backend for an Android App) so I created a project using maven:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.10 -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:
```

and selecting archetype `hello-endpoints-archetype` to have some sample code to work on.
This works well and my app is correctly calling the service as expected (and the service is correctly supplying the data in return).

Now I have to implement an "update" service to periodically (4 to 6 times a dya) update the data supplied to the app. So I added a servlet to my project to be called by cron. Trouble is: one of the library used during this update uses multi-threads which cause an AccessControlException to be thrown because apparently multi-thread is only allowed in backend modules...

But after having read dozens of pages on google app engine, I still don't know how to "break" my application into modules so that particular servlet would be run as a backend module while the already existing servlet keep working as they do. So far, all I got was that I should use an EAR application composed of several WAR modules, but I don't even know if my current application is an EAR or not...

I'm using Eclipse Luna, maven 3.2.1 (embeded with Eclipse), google app engine 1.9.10, writing in Java

Could anyone please help me by explaining the directory structure and/or configuration files I have to look at, modify and/or add?

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of multi-[modules project here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java).

However, note that even in backend modules the threading is limited to 50 threads, [as stated here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager).

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at that project (and validate your answer if I solve my problem).